# Jmeter beanshell Post Processor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How can I use beanshell Post Processor for analyze data from each request ?
I need analyze request and if request PASS - write in file, if request FAIL - write in other file.
Any body can write simple example script for this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the passed and failed requests in different files, you can use **[View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)** listener element, no need of beanshell Post processor and beanshell scripting. Add two View results tree() elements to thread group. For saving requests that are passed, tick **Successes** under Log/Display only option. Also provide a file path for saving these requests. To store failed requests check **Errors** in second view results tree element and file path as in figure. You can decide what to be stored under **Configure** button.

Note: This consumes more memory and should not be used for huge load.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SampleResult res = ctx.getPreviousResult();

if(res.isSuccessful()) {
    String DirPath = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();

    // write into jmeter.log file under Jmeter/bin directory
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(DirPath + File.separator + "SuccessFile"+"."+ fileSize, "rw");
    f.writeUTF(DirPath.toString());
    f.writeUTF("test.txt");
} else {
 // do same thing to create a file for failure.
}
```